# Textbox autocomplete - input from custom keyboard on screen

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I'm trying to use autocomplete. The input text comes from a custom made keyboard, made from a form.
I tried autocomplete feature from a simple textbox and text input from my keyboard and works fine. But when I input text from the custom keyboard, it doesn't work. The custom keyboard adds the input from a key listener `Key_Click`.
I tried adding an extra 'a' and adding the text as `txtInput.Text += 'o';` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

[image: Customkeyboard]

**keyboard code:**

```
public partial class frmTextInput : Form
{
    public string input_Text { get; set; }

    public frmTextInput(string TEXT,bool CTRL)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        AlternarTeclas(chkShift.Checked);
        AgregarListenerTeclas();
        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        List<string> box = Data.Data.SourcePatente();
        foreach (var item in box)
        {
            source.Add(item);
        }
        txtInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        txtInput.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtInput.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }


    private void btnSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text = txtInput.Text + " ";
    }

    private void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = txtInput.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            txtInput.Text = str.TrimEnd(str[str.Length - 1]);
        }
    }

    private void btnVolver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        input_Text = txtInput.Text;
    }

    private void frmTextInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void chkShift_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlternarTeclas(chkShift.Checked);
    }

    private void Key_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string key = sender.ToString();

        if (chkShift.Checked)
        {
            key = key.ToUpper();
        }
        else
        {
            key = key.ToLower();
        }

        txtInput.Text = txtInput.Text + key.Substring(key.Length - 1);
    }

    private void AgregarListenerTeclas()
    {
        foreach (Control c in tabCaracteres.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                if (c.Text.Length == 1 && c.Text != "←")
                {
                    c.Click += Key_Click;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Control c in tabSymbol.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                if (c.Text.Length == 1 && c.Text != "←")
                {
                    c.Click += Key_Click;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AlternarTeclas(bool estaShiftApretado)
    {
        if (estaShiftApretado)
        {
            foreach (Control c in tabCaracteres.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    if (c.Text.Length < 2)
                    {
                        c.Text = c.Text.ToUpper();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control c in tabCaracteres.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    if (c.Text.Length < 2)
                    {
                        c.Text = c.Text.ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void btnSymbol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabTeclado.SelectTab(tabTeclado.SelectedIndex + 1);
    }

    private void btnTecAlfanumerico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabTeclado.SelectTab(tabTeclado.SelectedIndex - 1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text += 'o';
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
txtInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
txtInput.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
txtInput.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

This should be put in the designer file of your textbox, not here. Try that, and can you see your textbox text value change when you use the custom keyboard? What I understand is you catch click event for your custom keyboard and change `txtInput.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. First of all, it didn't work with textbox multiline.
Then, the correct way to input new chars was emulate the keyboard:
I was triying in function "Key_Click":

== txtInput.Text = txtInput.Text + key.Substring(key.Length - 1);   ==> I don't work

Instead I used:

== txtInput.Focus(); // IMPORTANT

SendKeys.Send(key.Substring(key.Length - 1));